# PostgreSQL: VB.NET ODBC UPDATE not working properly

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc

VB.NET 2019

Postgre 10

Postgre ODBC

Source data in DBeaver:

https://i86.fastpic.ru/big/2019/0716/b9/_8741664f3e9495646d995a9d96b846b9.png

Tried to change SQL state, change parameters passing:

```
'Dim command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("UPDATE public.v8users SET Data = @data WHERE ID = @id", Connection) 'MSSQL syntax
'Dim command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("UPDATE public.v8users SET data = ?, name = ? WHERE id = ?", Connection)
'Dim command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("UPDATE public.v8users SET data = ?data WHERE id = ?id", Connection) 'MySQL syntax
'Dim command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("UPDATE public.v8users SET data = ? WHERE id = decode(encode(?, 'hex'), 'hex')", Connection) 'PostgreSQL syntax

'command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("@id", SQLUser.ID))
'command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("@data", NewBytes))
'command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("id", SqlDbType.Binary)).Value = SQLUser.ID
'command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("data", SqlDbType.Binary)).Value = NewBytes
'command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("name", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary)).Value = NewBytes
```

```
Structure SQLUser
   Dim ID As Byte()
   Dim IDStr As String
   Dim Name As String
   Dim Descr As String
   Dim Data As Byte()
   Dim DataStr As String
   Dim PassHash As String
   Dim PassHash2 As String
   Dim AdmRole As String
   Dim KeySize As Integer
   Dim KeyData As Byte()
End Structure

Dim a
Dim Connection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=192.168.2.10;Database=TestPurp;Uid=<correct>;Pwd=<correct>;UseServerSidePrepare=1;ReadOnly=0")
Dim command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand("UPDATE public.v8users SET data = ? WHERE id = ?", Connection)
command.Parameters.Clear()
command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("id", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary)).Value = SQLUser.ID
command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("data", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary)).Value = NewBytes
a = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

a = 0, expect a = 1

Comment: Try adding the Parameters in the same order as they appear in the Update statement. First add data then id.

Comment: WOW!!! That works! Holy .t!
I tormented with this whole week! Thank you!
How can i mark this as an answer?

Comment: I will post an answer and you can then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the Parameters in the same order as they appear in the Update statement. First add data then id.

```
command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("data", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary)).Value = NewBytes
command.Parameters.Add(New Odbc.OdbcParameter("id", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary)).Value = SQLUser.ID
```

This works the same way in Access with the OleDb provider.